# Как добавить бота на сервер дискорд по ссылке?

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

Есть аккаунт дискорда, есть все данные от него. Нужно чтобы при вводе, в консоль, ссылки на сервер дискорда, аккаунт присоединялся. Не могу разобраться с accept_invite, есть ли такая функция?

P.S. Это не просто бот, а self-bot. По факту это аккаунт, значит это возможно.

Comment: По факту селфботы запрещены в Discord, поэтому вам вряд ли помогут.

Answer (score 1):

Будет тяжело решить данную проблему через Python, а особенно через discord-py, Но есть  [программа](https://yougame.biz/threads/146469/) для ваших целей, вообще она предназначена для другого, но под ваши цели тоже подходит (если я вас правильно понял)

Comment: я все-таки нашел решение, можно это сделать через request.

Answer (score 0):

вот подходящий код

```
import requests
def join(token):
    header = {"authorization": token}
    r = requests.post('https://discordapp.com/api/v6/invites/ссылка на серв', headers=header)

join('token')
```